# JavaScript: changing the value of onclick with or without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, attributes

I'd like to change the value of the `onclick` attribute on an anchor. I want to set it to a new string that contains JavaScript. (That string is provided to the client-side JavaScript code by the server, and it can contains whatever you can put in the `onclick` attribute in HTML.) Here are a few things I tried:

- Using jQuery `attr("onclick", js)` doesn't work with both Firefox and IE6/7.
- Using `setAttribute("onclick", js)` works with Firefox and IE8, but not IE6/7.
- Using `onclick = function() { return eval(js); }` doesn't work because you are not allowed to use `return` is code passed to `eval()`.

Anyone has a suggestion on to set the onclick attribute to  to make this work for Firefox and IE 6/7/8? Also see below the code I used to test this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var js = "alert('B'); return false;";
                // Set with JQuery: doesn't work
                $("a").attr("onclick", js);
                // Set with setAttribute(): at least works with Firefox
                //document.getElementById("anchor").setAttribute("onclick", js);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" id="anchor" onclick="alert('A'); return false;">Click</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "with or with jQuery" would you like jQuery with that jQuery?

Comment: I assumed the OP wanted to jQuery while he jQueried.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `onClick` any more if you are using jQuery.  jQuery provides its own methods of attaching and binding events. See [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var js = "alert('B:' + this.id); return false;";
    // create a function from the "js" string
    var newclick = new Function(js);

    // clears onclick then sets click using jQuery
    $("#anchor").attr('onclick', '').click(newclick);
});
```

That should cancel the `onClick` function - and keep your "javascript from a string" as well.

The best thing to do would be to remove the `onclick=""` from the `<a>` element in the HTML code and switch to using the [**Unobtrusive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) method of binding an event to click.

You also said:

> Using `onclick = function() { return eval(js); }` doesn't work because you are not allowed to use return in code passed to eval().

No - it won't, but `onclick = eval("(function(){"+js+"})");` will wrap the 'js' variable in a function enclosure.  `onclick = new Function(js);` works as well and is a little cleaner to read.  (note the capital F) -- see [documentation on `Function()` constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: attr('onclick', '') doesn't work, you'll need to use removeAttr('onclick')

Comment: Beware of this as well: jQuery unbind() vs removeAttr() see http://www.novogeek.com/post/2009/05/18/Beware-e28093-jQuery-unbind()-vs-removeAttr().aspx

Answer (score 3):

BTW, without JQuery this could also be done, but obviously it's pretty ugly as it only considers IE/non-IE:

```
if(isie)
   tmpobject.setAttribute('onclick',(new Function(tmp.nextSibling.getAttributeNode('onclick').value)));
else
   $(tmpobject).attr('onclick',tmp.nextSibling.attributes[0].value); //this even supposes index
```

Anyway, just so that people have an overall idea of what can be done, as I'm sure many have stumbled upon this annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha with Jquery is that the click function do not acknowledge the hand coded onclick from the html.

So, you pretty much have to choose. Set up all your handlers in the init function or all of them in html.

The click event in JQuery is the click function $("myelt").click (function ....).

Comment: Tom, I can't use $("myelt").click() here because the code I want to run is in a string. (See my comments to other answers here as well.)

Comment: Ah.  I see how about: function js() { alert('B'); return false; }

Answer (score 0):

just use jQuery bind method !jquery-selector!.bind('event', !fn!);

[See here for more about events in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually navigate to a new page you can also have your anchor somewhere on the page like this.

```
<a id="the_anchor" href="">
```

And then to assign your string of JavaScript to the the onclick of the anchor, put this somewhere else (i.e. the header, later in the body, whatever):

```
<script>
    var js = "alert('I am your string of JavaScript');"; // js is your string of script
    document.getElementById('the_anchor').href = 'javascript:' + js;
</script>
```

If you have all of this info on the server before sending out the page, then you could also simply place the JavaScript directly in the `href` attribute of the anchor like so:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('I am your script.'); alert('So am I.');">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that following gnarf's idea you can also do:

```
var js = "alert('B:' + this.id); return false;";<br/>
var newclick = eval("(function(){"+js+"});");<br/>
$("a").get(0).onclick = newclick;
```

That will set the onclick without triggering the event (had the same problem here and it took me some time to find out).

Answer (score -3):

Came up with a quick and dirty fix to this. Just used `<select onchange='this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick();> <option onclick='alert("hello world")' ></option> </select>`

Hope this helps

Comment: Mmmh... sorry but I don't see how this is answer to the original question.