# Javascript DOM errors

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome

this is my javascript code , I am trying to create a dynamic list in HTML with data I recieve from the server , The data is of type "json"

My Javascript snippet

```
function addBooks(data) { // USing DOM to populate the tables 


    //var  newdata=document.getElementById('addBooks');
    //newdata.setattribute()

    //get the unordered list

    var newdata = document.getElementById('addBooks');
    var parent = document.getElementById('gBookList');
    //removeChildrenFromNode(parent);

    //create list divider
    var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
    listdiv.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListDiv');
    listdiv.innerHTML = ("Books Found:");
    parent.appendChild(listdiv);
    // (this is where the first error happens)

    //create dynamic list

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // (this is where the second error happens)



        //create each list item 
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListItem');
        parent.appendChild(listItem);
        //var link = document.createElement('a');
        //link.setAttribute('onclick','displayBook(data[i])');
        //link.setAttribute('href','#FindBook)');
        //listItem.appendChild(link);
        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        pic.setAttribute('src', data[i].pictureURL);
        pic.setAttribute('width', '80px');
        pic.setAttribute('height', '100px');
        pic.setAttribute('style', 'padding-left: 10px');
        link.appendChild(pic);
        var brk = document.createElement('br')
        link.appendChild(brk);
        var title = document.createElement('p');
        title.innerHTML = data[i].title;
        title.setAttribute = ('style', 'float:right');
        link.appendChild(title);
        var author = document.createElement('p');
        author.innerHTML = data[i].author;
        link.appendChild(author);
    }
    var list = document.getElementById('gBookList');
    // $(list).listview("refresh");
}

/*function removeChildrenFromNode(node){
            while (node.hasChildNodes()){
                node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
            }
        //}*/
```

My html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
   <script ...> 
 <head>                  
<body onLoad="addBooks()">
    <div id="addBooks" class="row-fluid">
        <div id="gBookList">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the following error which prevents me from populating the list , I am using chrome

1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I do not understand why this should happen as the .length commands returns the correct integer ( amount of json objects) when I debug using a alert box .

the function that calls it

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ........,
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (xhr, statusText) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        window.location.replace("Page2_updated.html");
        addBooks(data); // Passing JSON to be replaced on page
    },

    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
        alert('error');
    },
```

### });

Edit

I changed my HTML file to the following structure after advice on this forum

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1" "display:block">
</div>
<div id="2" "display:none">  // no onLoad() anymore!!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited this part int he calling function

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ........,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (xhr, statusText) {
            alert(xhr.status);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(document.getElementById(1).style.display == "block"){ 
                document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none"; 
                document.getElementById(2).style.display = "block"; }
            addBooks(data); // Passing JSON to be replaced on page
        },

        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
            alert('error');
        },
    });
```

But I still get the following errors
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: SO copes well with HTML tags. Also, you appear to be closing the head tag after the body tag is closed. This is not correct.

Comment: Looks like SO can output HTML code perfectly...

Comment: Print your "data" variable, seems to be null cause of the errors you said.

Comment: aplogies , SO does display the elements correctly , edited!!

Comment: Not really the issue (I think), but there's no need to use setAttribute for everything. `listdiv.id = 'something'` or `pic.src =...` should work just fine ? especially setting styles that way seems strange to me.

Comment: removed the jQuery tag as you are not using any jQuery

Comment: Double-check the HTML you posted, you are clearly missing a HTML tag, and you have 2 opening HEADs.

Comment: @RahulKumar I can't see where you created the HTMLElement `link` so this line `link.appendChild(title)` should cause an error I think.  You've commented out where you created the `link` element. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code that builds a list. Compare with your version to see where you made the mistakes, in both mark up and code.

The source of your second error is incorrect data (most likely null) being passed to the addBooks function, so you would have to fix that.

Chrome and Firebug have excellent JavaScript debuggers with breakpoints, so use that to your advantage to identify the issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgth2/

EDIT:

Your problem is gleamingly obvious, after your comments and updates to the question:

1. Your first page is loading the JSON data from the service, but then does `window.location.replace("Page2 Updated.html");`, which sends the browser to the new page (notice that you're calling `addBooks(data);` immediately after. But that code is never executed because browser has already gone to another page
2. Your second page has `<body onload="addBooks();">` in it, which will cause the function to be called with a `null` data. This is the cause of your problem.

SOLUTION:

Number one suggestion would be to start using jQuery for everything else you're doing, and not just for the AJAX call.

Secondly, you should have the ajax call and the results rendering in one page, as it does not make any sense to redirect the browser to another page. Because your javascript always works in the context of a single page. As soon as you do something like `window.location.replace(..)` you end up losing everything you've done in the current page.

If you make these changes, you will see that your list loads just fine!

Comment: Thank you , This reinforces that my code is right!! but I am still facing the errors , I am not sure it is because of the data or something else .

Comment: @RahulKumar, your first error is most likely because of incorrect markup in the page (post full markup). Second error is most definetly because you're passing `null` data into `addBooks`, so post the code that calls it.

Comment: I reckon you may be right , the function that calls it        $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ........,
   dataType: "json",
   complete: function(xhr, statusText){
       alert(xhr.status); 
       },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {   
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   window.location.replace("Page2_updated.html");
   addBooks(data);  // Passing JSON to be replaced on page
  
   },// change this  
     error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               alert(data);
               alert('error');
               
               }, 
 });
}

Comment: I have also added the calling code to the question to make it more readable

Comment: Also the body of page 2 is the above mention HTML code with this modification <body onLoad="addBooks()">

Comment: @Strelok Sorry Strelok, I didn't read your fiddle properly before adding my answer.  You have uncommented what seems to me the crucial line ` var link = document.createElement('a');`  If Rahul doesn't create the link, he can't append a child to it.

Comment: @Strelok , Thank you for the solution ,   I am a little confused by "Number one suggestion would be to start using jQuery for everything else you're doing, and not just for the AJAX call."  I did read up on some Jquery mobile where we have <div data-role="" id=""> , I am not sure if we have something like that for Jquery , I am sure this is a very naive question but the best I could come up with was <div block-hidden>

Comment: I have edited my question , I have used <div "display:block"> and <div "display:none>

Answer (score 0):

This line in your loop creates multiple list items with the same ID:

```
listItem.setAttribute('id','gBookListItem');
```

try removing it - i don't think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

That's an error :

```
title.setAttribute=('style','float:right');
```

do:

```
var title = document.createElement('p');
    title.innerHTML = data[i].title;
    title.style.cssFloat = 'right';
link.appendChild(title);
```

and

```
var pic = document.createElement('img');
    pic.src = data[i].pictureURL;
    pic.width = '80px';
    pic.height = '100px';
    pic.style.paddingLeft = '10px';
link.appendChild(pic);
```

etc......

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that you're accidentally calling `addBooks()` somewhere in your code without any `data`?

Comment: Is it only called in one place?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to cut it down to the barebones and I'm pretty sure the fact that `link` is undefined is the reason you get an error when you call appendChild. It's certainly the first error I found in the console in Firebug. The following barebones sequence works in Firefox (sorry I don't have Chrome):

```
    var json =[
        {"pictureURL":"/test1.jpg/","title":"test1"},
        {"pictureURL":"/test2.jpg/", "title":"test2"},
        {"pictureURL":"/test3.jpg", "title":"test3"}
    ];
    function displayBook(title){
        alert(title);
        return false;
    }
    function addBooks(data) {
        var  newdata=document.getElementById('addBooks');
        var parent = document.getElementById('gBookList');
        var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
        listdiv.id = 'gBookListDiv';
        listdiv.innerHTML = "Books Found:";
        parent.appendChild(listdiv);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.id = 'gBookListItem-' + i;
            parent.appendChild(listItem);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.id = listItem.id + "-link";
            link.href = '#FindBook';
            link.innerHTML = data[i].title;
            listItem.appendChild(link);
            link.setAttribute("onclick", "return displayBook('" + data[i].title + "');");
            var pic = document.createElement('img');
            pic.src = data[i].pictureURL;
        }
        var list = document.getElementById('gBookList');
    }
```

I discovered from this answer [JavaScript: changing the value of onclick with or without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826628/javascript-changing-the-value-of-onclick-with-or-without-jquery) that I had to use setAttribute to add the onclick handler. I'm used to adding other attributes like `id` directly as mentioned by adeneo without calling setAttribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I think its more of an issue of transferring json data between pages , you can refer to the amendments I made in the question

Comment: @RahulKumar I still don't know why you've commented out the `link = document.createElement('a')` section of your code.

Comment: That was supposed to make it a link to redirect it to some other page , but that is beyond what problem I am facing .

Comment: Not when `link.appendChild(author);` raises an error in the code you posted. You should also comment out that line and see where you are.