# JSON data passing between html pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript DOM errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622324/javascript-dom-errors)

I have my following html code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1" "display:block">
</div>
<div id="2" "display:none">  // no onLoad() anymore!!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ........,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (xhr, statusText) {
            alert(xhr.status);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(document.getElementById(1).style.display == "block"){ 
                document.getElementById(1).style.display = "none"; 
                document.getElementById(2).style.display = "block"; }
            addBooks(data); // Passing JSON to be replaced on page
        },

        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
            alert('error');
        },
    });

function addBooks(data) { // USing DOM to populate the tables 


    //var  newdata=document.getElementById('addBooks');
    //newdata.setattribute()

    //get the unordered list

    var newdata = document.getElementById('addBooks');
    var parent = document.getElementById('gBookList');
    //removeChildrenFromNode(parent);

    //create list divider
    var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
    listdiv.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListDiv');
    listdiv.innerHTML = ("Books Found:");
    parent.appendChild(listdiv);
    // (this is where the first error happens)

    //create dynamic list

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // (this is where the second error happens)



        //create each list item 
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.setAttribute('id', 'gBookListItem');
        parent.appendChild(listItem);
        //var link = document.createElement('a');
        //link.setAttribute('onclick','displayBook(data[i])');
        //link.setAttribute('href','#FindBook)');
        //listItem.appendChild(link);
        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        pic.setAttribute('src', data[i].pictureURL);
        pic.setAttribute('width', '80px');
        pic.setAttribute('height', '100px');
        pic.setAttribute('style', 'padding-left: 10px');
        link.appendChild(pic);
        var brk = document.createElement('br')
        link.appendChild(brk);
        var title = document.createElement('p');
        title.innerHTML = data[i].title;
        title.setAttribute = ('style', 'float:right');
        link.appendChild(title);
        var author = document.createElement('p');
        author.innerHTML = data[i].author;
        link.appendChild(author);
    }
    var list = document.getElementById('gBookList');
    // $(list).listview("refresh");
}

/*function removeChildrenFromNode(node){
            while (node.hasChildNodes()){
                node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
            }
        //}*/
```

I keep getting the following error which prevents me from populating the list , I am using Chrome

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I have posted this question yesterday, but I just wanted a fresh perspective on what the error could be.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622324/javascript-dom-errors)?

Comment: yes , I did , I mentioned it in the question

Comment: Cleanup your old question (e.g. fix the code formatting). If you had more rep you could also start a bounty on it to get some more attention on it.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you should not ask the exact same question twice. You should make edits to your original question or ask those who have posted answers for clarification or more information. You've also accepted an answer on your original question, which indicates that your issue has been resolved. Please try to work within the original question.

Comment: Ok , Apologies , I am new to SO , thank you I have made the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a few issues here :-

- Are you doing this cross domain? If you are consider using JSONP instead which will solve some of the issues you may be seeing with data being "withheld" due to security policies.
- You are also accessing a varible and making a assumption it has a value

  `var parent = document.getElementById('gBookList');`

  Before you use the parent tag, you should ensure that its not null (or a empty reference) and that the element (gBookList) does infact exist in your document.

Answer (score 0):

must uncomment

```
// var link = document.createElement('a');
```

in

```
link.appendChild(pic);
```

this element is not decalred yet (in your case is just commented)!