# Understanding of ajax returning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some problems with understanding of ajax use.
Let's say I have file like this (this is just a pseudo code, dont look at the basic mistakes right now please) I have read so many articles, but i find them so hard to understand

```
///////////////// file 1 /////////////////
        <?php
        x = 1;
        <button onclick=somefunction(x)></button>
        ?>

        <script>
        //here goes some ajax code sending this x variable to another php file
        </script>
```

Lets say it looks like this

```
////////////// file 2 ////////////////
    <?php
    /get x variable + sendint it back
    return x=2
    ?>
```

Now what i want to do is to make this x value come back to the first script and make x=2. How do i do this?

Comment: Can you tell me which articles you have read ? because Ajax is not usefull to pass a variable from PHP to Javascript / HTML.

Comment: if this is pseudocode, why are you mixing php and js? (html/js inside php) your post is very confusing. Please fix it.

Comment: Well i can pass it into the php, but it need to come back from one file to another. Isnt it what return does? returning :D?

Comment: sigh so confusing.. so when you click your button, you want `2` to return and what do you want to do with that?

Comment: Well all i want is my php variable X = 1 to become X = 2 after using the external php by ajax.

Comment: The x in your upper example is a PHP variable. It no longer exists by the time you do your AJAX call.

Comment: are you open to changing your `onclick=somefunction(x)` to a jquery `.click(somefunction(x));`? It would be easier to change the `x` value if it is not in a `onclick()`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept of "statelessness".  Ajax will call your PHP script.  This will let you increase your variable when PHP runs.  Then the PHP script will terminate and the variable will be reset to its initial value the next time the PHP runs.  You won't be able to access the variable elsewhere on the frontend page unless you return a value from PHP back to the javascript.

Comment: well im trying to do this on the webpage, without refreshing it. Thats my point to change this variable in a static (non refreshing) way by ajax. After refreshing webpage it can come back to the previous value, whatever :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using JQuery with some notes to try to describe what happens.

```
<html>
<!--file: ajax_basic.php-->
<head>
    <title>Ajax Basic Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="example_input" value="1">
  <button id="example_button">Example</button>        
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // .click(function() executes an anonymous function when the button is clicked
            $('#example_button').click(function() {

                // get the current value from the input
                test_value = $('#example_input').val();

                // $.get is the AJAX method.
                // It sends the object {'sent_value': test_value} to test.php
                // function(response) is the the function that will be executed when
                // a response is returned from the test.php
                $.get('test.php', {'sent_value': test_value}, function(response) {
                    // here, x is taken from the response of the php script.
                    // You can do whatever you like with this value.
                    x = response.returned_value;

                    // for this example, it updates the value of the text input
                    $('#example_input').val(x);
                }, 'json');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP file that will handle the request. All it does for this example is increment the value it receives and return the new value.

```
<?php
// file: test.php
$response = array('returned_value' => $_GET['sent_value'] + 1);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you should switch from `onclick=somefunction(x)` to a jQuery binding, ie. `.on()`/`.click()`/etc. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/826697/689579

Using jQuery you could do something like-

```
<?php $x=1;>

<button id="mybutton">MyButton</button>

<script>
var x = <?php echo $x; ?>; // set initial x value to php value
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(somefunction);
});
function somefunction(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phppage.php',
        data: {number:x}, // send current x value
        ...
        success: function(result){
            x = result; // when php file returns 2 (or other value increase x
        }
    });
}
</script>
```